# OutOfMemoryException with Clipboard.GetData and PRTSC

Tags: wpf, clipboard, out-of-memory

I'm using :

```
SendKeys.SendWait("+{PRTSC}");
InteropBitmap interopBitmap = System.Windows.Clipboard.GetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.Bitmap) as InteropBitmap;
```

On my computer, everything is ok.
On another computer, I get an OutOfMemoryException.
Why ?
How to solve it ?

Thanks in advance for your answer

Comment: Is one 64 bit and one 32 bit? The 64 bit computer will have larger memory capacity.

Comment: I have a 64 bit one, the other computer is a 32 bit one.
A 32 bit one is unable to make a print screen of a 2-screen desktop ?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't Graphics.CopyFromScreen() be a more elegant solution?

Comment: It's more complex.
If I have many screen, it's hard to know the global size of all the screen. Except if there's a ready api